# open div in new window on row click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to open div in new window on row click  . i tried this .. div open in new window but the problem is that this is display only 1 div whereas i have 2 divs and second problem is when this is open then there is no demo bar and menu display where as i want to display these with div when div is open in new window

this is what i tried

[link js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8dXvt/1480/)

```js
$(function() {
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
      renderTo: 'sumdata',
      type: 'pie',
      width: 500,
      borderWidth: 2,
      events: {
        load: function(event) {
          var total = 0;
          for (var i = 0, len = this.series[0].yData.length; i < len; i++) {
            total += this.series[0].yData[i];
          }
          var text = this.renderer.text(
            'Total: ' + total,
            this.plotLeft,
            this.plotTop - 20
          ).attr({
            zIndex: 5
          }).add()
        }
      }
    },

    title: {
      text: 'demo'
    },

    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },

    legend: {
      layout: 'vertical',
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      y: 30,
      labelFormat: '{name} ({y})',
      navigation: {
        activeColor: '#3E576F',
        animation: true,
        arrowSize: 12,
        inactiveColor: '#CCC',
        style: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          color: '#333',
          fontSize: '12px'
        }
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 2) + '%<br />' + '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b><br />Rs.: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
      }
    },
    series: [{
      data: (function() {
        var names = 'grapes,lemon,orange,sugar,tea,pine',
          arr = [];

        Highcharts.each(names.split(','), function(name) {
          arr.push({
            name: name,
            y: Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
          });
        });

        return arr;
      }()),
      showInLegend: true
    }]

  });
});



$(function() {
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      type: 'pie',
      width: 500,
      borderWidth: 2,
      events: {
        load: function(event) {
          var total = 0;
          for (var i = 0, len = this.series[0].yData.length; i < len; i++) {
            total += this.series[0].yData[i];
          }
          var text = this.renderer.text(
            'Total: ' + total,
            this.plotLeft,
            this.plotTop - 20
          ).attr({
            zIndex: 5
          }).add()
        }
      }
    },

    title: {
      text: 'demo'
    },

    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },

    legend: {
      layout: 'vertical',
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      y: 30,
      labelFormat: '{name} ({y})',
      navigation: {
        activeColor: '#3E576F',
        animation: true,
        arrowSize: 12,
        inactiveColor: '#CCC',
        style: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          color: '#333',
          fontSize: '12px'
        }
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 2) + '%<br />' + '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b><br />Rs.: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
      }
    },
    series: [{
      data: (function() {
        var names = 'Ari,Bjartur,Bogi,Bragi,Dánjal,Dávur,Eli,Emil,Fróði,Hákun,Hanus,Hjalti,Ísakur,' +
          'Johan,Jóhan,Julian,Kristian,Leon,Levi,Magnus,Martin,Mattias,Mikkjal,Nóa,Óli,Pauli,Petur,Rói,Sveinur,Teitur',
          arr = [];

        Highcharts.each(names.split(','), function(name) {
          arr.push({
            name: name,
            y: Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
          });
        });

        return arr;
      }()),
      showInLegend: true
    }]

  });
});

function nWin() {
  var w = window.open();

  var html1 = $("#container").html();
  var html2 = $("#sumdata").html();

  $(w.document.body).html(html1, html2);
  //$(w.document.body).html(htmll);
}
$(function() {
  $('#tabledata').on('click', 'tr', (nWin))
    //  $("a#print").click(nWin);
});
```

```css
.lefttabs {
  background-color: #1E1E1E;
  color: White;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: medium;
  margin-top: 12px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 400px;
  z-index: 10;
  /
}
.lefttabs li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: -30px;
}
#tabledata {
  margin-left: 160px;
}
#cont {
  margin-left: 160px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#sumdata {
  margin-left: 160px;
}
.bar {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div class="bar">
  demo
</div>
<div class="lefttabs">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>DASHBOARD</a> 
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>EVENTS</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<table id="tabledata">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>
        1
      </td>
      <td>
        2
      </td>
      <td>
        3
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        1data
      </td>
      <td>
        2data
      </td>
      <td>
        3data
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        data1
      </td>
      <td>
        data2
      </td>
      <td>
        data3
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<div id="container" style="width: 50px; height: 200px;margin-left: 170px;display:none"></div>
<br />
<div id="sumdata" style="width: 50px; height: 200px;margin-left: 170px;display:none"></div>
```

Comment: `$(w.document.body).html(html1, html2);` won't work. Look at the definition of .html() (http://api.jquery.com/html/) - it only accepts one argument. You could try concatenating them: `$(w.document.body).html(html1 + html2);`

Comment: @ADyson so what i do

Comment: @ADyson this is not working

Comment: not working how? What does happen? Any errors?

Comment: @ADyson ok this is working .. but the bar and menu how i display this with highcharts div

Comment: instead of replacing the entire body of your second page with the contents of html1 and html2, include the other content as well. Html1 and html2 could go within another div within that structure.

Comment: @ADyson means? sorry i did not understand your point

Comment: well if you need other contents, include them as well when you make your HTML. So then html1 and html2 are only part of the new page, not the whole body. So you need to include "bar" and "lefttabs" HTML as well. And probably you need to set the CSS of the new window.

Comment: means i re write whole css again ?

Comment: i do this but css is not working.. @ADyson

Comment: how did you include the CSS? Separate file or in a `<style>` tag?

Comment: there is also a separate file but css not reflect

Comment: did you include a reference to the CSS in the new window? e.g. via inputting a `<link href="`...etc string into the new window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use append method instead of html method . 
i have updated fiddle . 

  http://jsfiddle.net/8dXvt/1481/

Comment: but also how to display demo and menu bar with these divs?

Comment: like this also use append method of div element

Comment: but css is not working and also this append not working when i try in my project

Comment: append is working in fiddle but when i do this in my project then both divs not display only 1 div is display .. and one thing more why u create whole css like this.. var html3 = $('<div class="bar">demo</div>').css({"background-color": "blue", "font-size": "200%"});
     ......... i have many content so this is not making any sense to write whole  css.

Comment: i cannot edit in your project . i can only edit in fiddle and that's working fine :)

Comment: and i apologize for adding css their . i am trying to achieve that

Comment: ok this is working .. but the bar and menu how i display this with highcharts div

Comment: this is so confusing.. means there is lot of css and i did not write whole css in style... any other option?